# Looking up multiple dictionary keys in a Pandas Dataframe & return multiple values for matches

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, string-matching

First time posting so apologies in advance if my formatting is off.

Here's my issue:

I've created a Pandas dataframe which contains multiple rows of text:

```
d = {'keywords' :['cheap shoes', 'luxury shoes', 'cheap hiking shoes']}
keywords = pd.DataFrame(d,columns=['keywords'])
In [7]: keywords
Out[7]:
        keywords
0  cheap shoes
1  luxury shoes
2  cheap hiking shoes
```

Now I have a dictionary that contains the following keys / values:

```
labels = {'cheap' : 'budget', 'luxury' : 'expensive', 'hiking' : 'sport'}
```

What I would like to do is find out whether a key in the dictionary exist in the dataframe, and if so, return the appropriate value

I was able to somewhat get there using the following:

```
for k,v in labels.items():
   keywords['Labels'] = np.where(keywords['keywords'].str.contains(k),v,'No Match')
```

However, the output is missing the first two keys and is only catching the last "hiking" key

```
    keywords            Labels
0   cheap shoes         No Match
1   luxury shoes        No Match
2   cheap hiking shoes  sport
```

Additionally, I'd also like to know if there's a way to catch multiple values in the dictionary separated by | , so the ideal output would look like this

```
    keywords            Labels
0   cheap shoes         budget
1   luxury shoes        expensive
2   cheap hiking shoes  budget | sport
```

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's certainly possible. Here is one way.

```
d = {'keywords': ['cheap shoes', 'luxury shoes', 'cheap hiking shoes', 'nothing']}

keywords = pd.DataFrame(d,columns=['keywords'])

labels = {'cheap': 'budget', 'luxury': 'expensive', 'hiking': 'sport'}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

def matcher(k):
    x = (i for i in labels if i in k)
    return ' | '.join(map(labels.get, x))

df['values'] = df['keywords'].map(matcher)

#              keywords          values
# 0         cheap shoes          budget
# 1        luxury shoes       expensive
# 2  cheap hiking shoes  budget | sport
# 3             nothing
```

Comment: the above works great but one follow up. How would you edit the above to only capture exact matches? For example, if the labels were updated to include 'cheape':'budget' and the first keyword was updated to 'cheapest cheap shoes'. Running the above script would produce budget | budget as the values for "cheapest cheap shoes"

Comment: The dictionary can potentially grow to house more variants of word tied to a single value.

Comment: You should use sets instead, e.g. `return {labels[i] for i in labels if i in k}`

Comment: The above works great to remove the duplicate values from the final result. I'm still getting a weird error with partial matches though. Suppose I add in liverpool to keywords `d = {'keywords': ['cheapest cheap shoes', 'luxury shoes', 'cheap hiking shoes', 'liverpool']}` and 'pool' to labels `labels = {'cheape': 'budget','cheap': 'budget', 'luxury': 'expensive', 'hiking': 'sport', 'pool':'swimming'}`

Comment: running the script will then net `keywords values
0 cheapest cheap shoes {budget}
1 luxury shoes {expensive}
2 cheap hiking shoes {budget, sport}
3 liverpool {swimming}`

seem's like it's still partial matching pool to liverpool

Comment: I'm afraid your entire question has changed. Before you were looking to match substrings, now you're looking to match words. I suggest you start a new question on this clearly stating your requirements.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for the help you definitely got me further down the road. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `"|".join(labels.keys())` to get a pattern to be used by `re.findall()`.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

d = {'keywords' :['cheap shoes', 'luxury shoes', 'cheap hiking shoes']}
keywords = pd.DataFrame(d,columns=['keywords'])
labels = {'cheap' : 'budget', 'luxury' : 'expensive', 'hiking' : 'sport'}
pattern = "|".join(labels.keys())

def f(s):
    return "|".join(labels[word] for word in re.findall(pattern, s))

keywords.keywords.map(f)
```

Answer (score 2):

Sticking with your approach, you could do e.g.

```
arr = np.array([np.where(keywords['keywords'].str.contains(k), v, 'No Match') for k, v in labels.items()]).T
keywords["Labels"] = ["|".join(set(item[ind if ind.sum() == ind.shape[0] else ~ind])) for item, ind in zip(arr, (arr == "No Match"))]

Out[97]: 
             keywords        Labels
0         cheap shoes        budget
1        luxury shoes     expensive
2  cheap hiking shoes  sport|budget
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea of using `replace` first then finding the values.

```
keywords.assign(
    values=
    keywords.keywords.replace(labels, regex=True)
            .str.findall(f'({"|".join(labels.values())})')
            .str.join(' | ')
)

             keywords          values
0         cheap shoes          budget
1        luxury shoes       expensive
2  cheap hiking shoes  budget | sport
```

Answer (score 0):

You could [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) the strings into separate columns, then [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) into a multi index, so that you can [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html), the labels dictionary to the values. Then [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) the initial index, and [`concatenate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.cat.html) the strings that belong to each index

```
keywords['Labels'] = keywords.keywords.str.split(expand=True).stack()\
                     .map(labels).groupby(level=0)\
                     .apply(lambda x: x.str.cat(sep=' | '))



            keywords          Labels
0         cheap shoes          budget
1        luxury shoes       expensive
2  cheap hiking shoes  budget | sport
```